# Esconder elemento JSON usando javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte resultado em JSON:

```
 {
  "name": "test",
  "count": 5,
  "frequency": "Manual Crawl",
  "version": 1,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "thisversionrun": "Wed Jun 24 2015 16:25:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "property1": "",
        "property2": "DIA DA TERRA",
        "index": 1,
        "url": "http://site.com.br"
      },
```

Eu preciso mostrar somente o elemento property2, como esconder os demais elementos (property1, index, url) usando o javascript?

Comment: Como assim esconder? Não mostrar? Que o servidor só envie parte? Podes explicar melhor?

Comment: @Sergio esse resultado JSON mostra o seguinte na tela: DIA DA TERRA
index 1
url http://www.site.com.br, quando deveria mostrar apenas o DIA DA TERRA.

Comment: Voltei agora ao computador, já resolveste o problema? fui ao site mas não encontrei o que referes.

Comment: @Sergio ainda não descobri...

Comment: Tentie usar: return data[0].results.colletion1.property2; mas não deu certo. No caso era para mostrar somente o elemente property2

Comment: posta um pouco mais do seu código, assim fia mais facil ajudar

Answer (score 1):

e só usar como objeto exemplo:

```js
var json = {
  "name": "test",
  "count": 5,
  "frequency": "Manual Crawl",
  "version": 1,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "thisversionrun": "Wed Jun 24 2015 16:25:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
        
      {
        "property1": "",
        "property2": "DIA DA TERRA",
        "index": 1,
        "url": "http://site.com.br"
      },
      {
        "property1": "",
        "property2": "DIA DA TERRA 2",
        "index": 1,
        "url": "http://site.com.br"
      }
    ]
    
  }
}

alert(json.results.collection1[0].property2);
alert(json.results.collection1[1].property2);
```

apenas acessa-lo por objeto.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o6azw0u2/1/)

Comment: Gabriel, seria assim?  var resultados = ' { "results": { "property2":"DIA DA TERRA" }, }';
  var resultado = JSON.parse(resultados);
  alert(resultado.results);

Comment: alert(json.results.collection1[0].property2); e você pode percorrer pelos indices [0],[1],[2] até a informação do property acabar

Comment: Não funcionou. Vou ir testando aqui. Obg.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o6azw0u2/1/

Comment: Pelo menos onde estou programando (KimonoLabs) da o seguinte erro: "error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Your function failed to evaluate.". Vale lembrar que o servidor já inicia o javascript coma  seguinte função: function transform(data) {   return data; }

Comment: Tentei usar: return data.results.collection1[0].property2; . Ele retorna NULL.

Comment: executa o exemplo acima.

Answer (score 0):

**GustavoCave**, caso seu `JSON`venha como parâmetro de uma função ajax (ex: `success`, `done`, etc), considere literalmente OMITIR as chaves `propery1`, `index` e `url`.

**Exemplo**

```
$.ajax( "recuperaJSON.php" )
.done(function(resultado) {

    // EXIBIR SOMENTE PROPRIEDADE "property2"
    // para cada resultado
    $.each(data['results'], function(key, value) 
    {
        $.each(data['results'][key], function(key_result, value_result)
        {
            // considere haver um elemento HTML com id "idResultado", por exemplo 
            $('#idResultado').append(value_result['property2'] + "<br>");
        });    
    });

});
```

**Demonstração**

Veja seu JSON salvo numa variável chamada `json` e depois a iteração entre os resultados, exibindo **somente** *"propery2"*:

https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/a8y48k4m/

Answer (score 0):

Galera, consegui usando o seguinte:

```
function transform(data) { 
    data.results.collection1.map(function(item) {  
       delete item.index;  
       return item;  
    }); 
    return data; 
};
```